# what type of communication to use while making the application like uber

Tags: java, rest, sockets, java-websocket

I am working on an android application(backend coding) like uber, currently we are using websockets for communicating with server.
**Will it be better to use java sockets instead of websockets?**

**At server-side:**

*I am using JAVA,RESTful web service for receiving the request,like login,logout,change password,etc and saving the request to DB.
Using Websockets (after receiving the above request) for other logic (main logic like finding nearest agent, sending customer request to agent, sending agent response to customer using their sessions).*

**If** **YES**, what will be the reasons for sockets over websockets here?